# Adding weightage to number.

Tags: arithmetic

I have four numbers

```
x=50
y=30
z=20

sum of x+y+z=100
```

if i want to add a number n where

```
n=(x+y)/2
```

Edit:

```
   n=45
    such that x+y+z+n=100
```

now x+y+z=100.If any number (45 here) is added, then the sum should be always 100. i.e we need to subtract number(say m) from each x,y,z,n such that sum x+y+z+n should be equal to 100.

is it possible to do that.

Comment: in fact your equation is $3x+3y+2z=200$, now your question is that all natural's numbers such that satisfied this equation or not?

Comment: i want to maintain the weitage of number i.e if any number of variable is added to sum of x,y and z then the sum should always be 100. Also check the edit : n is having some value.

Comment: note that if $n=(x+y)/2$ and $n=50$, then must be have $z=0$, i think your question must be refine.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You seem to have **three** numbers, not four, $x+y+z = 110 \ne 100$, and you are asking how to add $n=45$ to what? I assume you know how numbers are added to each other, so what is your question?

Comment: sorry for mistake just check the question i have edited, now x+y+z=100.If any number (45 here) is added, then the sum should be always 100. i.e we need to subtract number(say x) from each x,y,z,n such that sum x+y+z+n should be equal to 100.

Comment: @user2749218 So, you want $(x-a)+(y-a)+(z-a)+n=100$, and your question is what is $a$?

Comment: yes exactly, you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = n/3$. Then

\begin{align*}
(x-a) + (y-a) + (z-a) + n &= x - n/3 + y - n/3 + z - n/3 + n \\
&= x + y + z + n - n = x + y + z.
\end{align*}

Comment: Let a=n/3, so what is 3.

Comment: 3 is the number of variables ($x,y,z$), so you end up with $-a-a-a = -3a = -n$ which cancel out the $n$ you want to add. In your case, $a = n/3 = 45/3 = 15$.